# Fourier Series Coefficients Calculation

Tags: signal, fourier

Could someone tell me where my calculation is going wrong?

So I integrate  $$\int_{-1}^1te^{-jn \pi\ t}\ dt$$ and get

$$\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }\text{+}\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-(jn \pi\ )^2}\text{+}\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }\text{ - }\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{-(jn \pi\ )^2}$$

which I can get to

$$\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }(1-\frac{1}{jn \pi\ })+\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }(1+\frac{1}{jn \pi\ })$$

The simplified answer is

$$\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }+e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }$$

I can do some simple simplification but I can't figure out how to get to that final answer

Comment: i'm not checking over your work to see that it is correct, but both \$ e^{j\pi} \$ and \$ e^{-j\pi} \$ are the same as \$-1\$.  so consider what \$(-1)^n\$ is (for even and odd \$n\$).

Comment: Its a cosine function I believe, but I don't understand how to get there with all of the extra jn * pi terms

Comment: \$n\$ is an integer, i believe.  so you don't need to express it as \$ \frac{2j}{n\pi} \cos(\pi n) \$.  you can, instead, express it more simply knowing that \$n\$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I try it the long way to give a proof of your simplified answer, and from the very first step to make sure that everybody knows what we are talking about (and to be very careful with the signs).
Problem:
$$\int_{-1}^1te^{-jn \pi\ t}\ dt  =?=?=  \frac{e^{jn \pi\ }  + e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ } $$

Let´s do it with the integration by parts. The template:

$$\int_{-a}^bf'(x)g(x)dx=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{a}^bf(x)g'(x)dx$$

We choose the following substitutions:
$$f'(x)=e^{-jn \pi\ t}$$ which integrates to 
$$f(x)=-\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ t}}{jn \pi\ t}$$
and
$$g(x) = t$$
derivative: $$g'(x) = 1$$

Next step, fill out, which leads to :

$$-\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ }(1) - \frac{e^{jn \pi\ } }{jn \pi\ }(1) - \int_{a}^b- \frac{e^{-jn \pi\ t}}{jn \pi\ t}(1)dt$$

(the first two (1)´s are the values for upper and lower boundary of the integral, the third (1) is the derivative g'(x), of $$g(x)$$, which is 1)

which, if further dissolved, leads to (consider the signs of the boundaries)

$$-\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ } - \frac{e^{jn \pi\ } }{jn \pi\ } - (-\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ } - \frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ } ) $$

and, only solving the term within the braces (how can we scratch terms out?):

$$-\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ } - \frac{e^{jn \pi\ } }{jn \pi\ } +\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ } - \frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{jn \pi\ } $$

which leads at the end to:

$$\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }  + e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ } $$

which is the proof for your assumption.

regards

Answer (score 1):

Assuming \$n\$ is an integer, and expanding the exponentials to \$cos\$ and \$sin\$ terms, all the \$sin\$ terms disappear, leaving:

$$\frac{e^{jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }(1-\frac{1}{jn \pi\ })+\frac{e^{-jn \pi\ }}{-jn \pi\ }(1+\frac{1}{jn \pi\ })=\frac{1}{-jn\pi}\:2\:cos(n\pi)=\frac{1}{-jn\pi}(e^{jn\pi}+e^{-jn\pi})$$